# Multiseat -Display numbers from the xservers are vary after each start

Tags: lightdm, multiseat

I am running a multi seat system with several graphics cards.
At the moment I am using lightdm as desktop manager.
I realized, that after each system start the display numbers vary.

Vary means:

Restart                                123456789

Seat0   Desktop number   011010001

Seat-1  Desktop number   100101110

Even if I mapped the GPU to a specific seat and desktop number.

I would like to know if there is a way to setup a deterministic multi seat system where  every time atfter a restart the desktop numbers are as specified in the config files.

Does anyone has an idea about this?

An abstract from the current config files:

xorg.conf

...

Section "ServerLayout"

```
   ...

    Option          "Seat"  "seat0"

...
```

EndSection

Section "Device"

```
...

    MatchSeat       "seat-1"

...
```

EndSection

lightdm.conf

...

[Seat:seat0]

xserver-command=/usr/lib/xorg/Xorg :0 -config xorg_seat0.conf -sharevts -keeptty

[Seat:seat-1]

xserver-command=/usr/lib/xorg/Xorg :1 -config xorg_seat-1.conf -sharevts -keeptty

Answer (score 0):

I face the same issue there is no config option to fix that for lightdm. The problem is that lightdm passes a display number based on the order of seats returned by logind.

For gdm it looks like you could.

So you could either write a script that filters or modifues specific display arguments and use that as your command or if you just want to know the lightdm display of a specific seat you still can use something like this.

```bsh
loginctl show-seat seatX -p ActiveSession
#extract the value and then
loginctl show-session value -p Display
```